# Erro Entity Framework | not handled in user code

Tags: entity-framework

Olá, preciso de ajuda no seguinte cenário.

Tenho uma classe, onde o campo é Int64 no backend e no SQL Server o campo é bigint.

```
ObjClasse.VariavelInteira = numInt;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Ao salvar, o erro que apresenta é:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred
>   in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Como posso identificar o erro?

Comment: `Classe` é um objeto? Ou uma classe acessando um membro estático?

Comment: Editei a pergunta para corrigir. Aproveitei para editar correspondendo à sua resposta. Pois ela foi crucial para eu identificar (e resolver) o problema. Obrigado.

Comment: Show! Sabia que com isso ia ser fácil de resolver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este é um erro genérico dizendo que alguma validação falhou. Para capturar o erro específico, você pode fazer o seguinte

```
try
{
    Classe.VariavelInteira = numInt;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{    
    var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
            .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
            .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

    var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);         
    var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);

    //Use a variável exceptionMessage para ver os erros de validação
}
```

Se depois disso, ainda precisar de ajuda, edite sua pergunta com os erros retornados.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795300/validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-see-entityvalidationerrors-propert

Comment: Não entendi. Desculpa.